# How to get chaincode to read from api's outside of the Hyperledger fabric blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm wondering how you can get a hyperledger fabric smart contract to read from external API's ?

A service called oraclize (http://www.oraclize.it/) is used to do this operation in Ethereum blockchains - Is there anything similar for hyperledger fabric smart contracts or any workarounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Hyperledger Fabric - smart contracts (the chaincode), could be implemented at the moment with either golang or Java, both of which are Turing complete and provides you with reach set of libraries and frameworks. Among which you can you any network library to get connected with external services, while you need to be extra cautious doing this to make sure your chaincode is deterministic (e.g. two independent executions of the same chaincode calling same external API will get same result back).

Comment: But keep in mind that this is not recommended, chaincode should focus on saving\ fetching data, and do some simple business logic, it should be fast, to avoid issues, also keep in mind that this is decentralized architecture, each endorsement peer shall do the same thing ( calling external API) and all must have connectivity

Answer (score 1):

Riccardo from Oraclize here.

We are actually working on a Oraclize integration with Hyperledger.

Comment: Oraclize documentation for Fabric here: https://docs.oraclize.it/#fabric