# Hyperledger fabric - Can I call external system during validation or Endorsement Phase

Tags: validation, hyperledger-fabric, external

We have a use case where a transaction validation logic is quite complex and requires data from different sources, in order to validate a transaction.

**Query**  Can we call and external rest service to validate certain data from hyperledger fabric, using its pluggable validation feature ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Hyperledger Fabric, can we enforce transaction to be validated by a legacy/off-chain system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773121/in-hyperledger-fabric-can-we-enforce-transaction-to-be-validated-by-a-legacy-of)

Answer (score 0):

Making an external api call from hyperledger fabric smart contract  is technically possible, it is a risky idea for several reasons:

1) chaincode must be deterministic, and the problem with 'enriching' a transaction using an external API is that it must return the same result running anywhere in a business network, which may very well be running globally, so you need to trust that the answers will all be the same within a time windows that is quite a bit wider than a few ms
2) running just one endorser in development *and* production gets you around that problem, but weakens consensus a bit, and makes it essentially impossible to prove determinism for any given transaction
3) designing to such a weakened system is not a good idea, since inevitably someone will realize that the endorsement policy should be stronger and you go right back to the issues in point 1

One way around this issue is to use a distributed external API with versioned data (and you might need to write an oracle to provide this facility on top of an API that is not versioning its data) such that all endorsers store the external data's current version in the asset repository in world state as well. This makes certain that the data read is identical and accounts for delays in propagation in the oracle network. The presence of the API data version in the final asset data in world state (more accurately in the read/write set for the transaction) ensures that different versions of data in different regions in the oracle (e.g. propagation delays) will fail any multi-endorsement policy. Of course, a client designed in such an environment is free to resubmit a transaction for endorsement to get consensus.